# Saving html page with @import in css

Tags: html, css

I want to save a complete html page.

The css file of the html document contains the following line:

```
import url('someOtherCss.css');
```

When I try to save the page with Firefox or Chrome with 'File->Save Page as...' this line is ignored.

How can I save this page including the someOtherCss.css document? I found that this bug is known in Firefox since 2002 https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=126309.

Is there any browser who supports this (Without adding the css files b hand)?

Comment: view source of that html and then copy, paste it into your file. and in addition you need to download `someOtherCss.css` and paste in same folder where `.html` is

Comment: @TechnoKnol If I would start this html file offline then I would not even have the .css file.

Comment: as i said in my previous comment that you have to download that css additionally in same folder to make it work.

Comment: @TechnoKnol okay - and also the other css, and all the images, and then I need to change all paths in the html document. I think one really should use "Save Page as..." I just dont want to include all the .css by hand.

Comment: @TechnoKnol you edited your comment while I was responding.

Comment: it's okay to save with `save as`, but as you mentioned that it's a bug, so i show you another way,

Answer (score 0):

You could save it as an MHT in Internet Explorer. It is a single web document (web archive). Not the same as an HTML page though...

Comment: Thank you, but I am really interested in a HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

Look at **[this sreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2yVH.png)** .

It's from Google Chrome Dev tools (press F12 to open) / Windows 7/

It desplays all the assets fetched from the server, including stylesheets. My best guess is that you will find it there and I'm afraid you have to download the stylesheet manually.